# Как правильно вставить абсолютный путь Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, java, html

```
<h5>Снаряжение</h5>
<div>Профессиональная экипировка</div>

<img src="C:/Users/ARTEM/IdeaProjects/market_project_img/main.jpg" alt="img1">
<img src="./src/main/resources/img/main.jpg" alt="img2">
<img src="./resources/img/main.jpg" alt="img3">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пишу в spring boot, и из view не могу найти файл с помощью относительного или абсолютного пути так как не знаю "точку отсчета". Если бы писал на javascript, то там я точно знаю, как из index.html "дойти" до файла. Но ты прав, это скорее не java а SpringBoot/Html.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением класса MvcConfig и переопределением метода addResourceHandlers с указанием нужных локаций.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:///" + uploadPath + "/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```